# Converter SWF para ficheiro interactivo em âmbiente IOS

Tags: ios

Boas!

Estou encarregue de desenvolver uma aplicação para Ipad que execute ficheiros swf (com interactividade). Uma vez que a Apple encerrou o suporte ao Flash, tenho de encontrar uma maneira de converter os ficheiros swf em ficheiros que suportem interactividade, em ambiente IOS.

Sabem-me ajudar?

Obrigado malta!

Comment: facil assim como converter swf para rodar no iphone acho que nao consegue nao, mas que fez em falsh tem o [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) voce escreve em AS3 e ele da saida para android e iphone

Comment: Olá! 
O problema não está no carregamento do swf, por AS3.
O problema está em como transferir os ficheiros swf para o ipad se o iTunes não os reconhece. Importar pela web não é solução.

Comment: Mas o que voce pretende fazer exatamente, como voce mesmo disse o iphone nao suporta mais o flash, como voce pretende rodar oswf se não é mais suportado? Para você subir a aplicacao no iphone como um app so vai conseguir depois que gerar um IPA a partir do adobeair

Comment: Exactamente. 
Peço desculpa, mas não me expressei correctamente:
Eu desenvolvi uma app (em Android e IOS) que se destina a mostrar diversos .swf's, como ficheiros externos. Acontece que, no caso do IOS, não vejo forma de reproduzir os swfs. Daí necessitar de os converter. Estou neste momento a estudar a possibilidade de converter os swf em .epub (com video e interactividade) e depois os carregar com AS3. Vês alguma solução para o meu problema? Muito Obrigado

Comment: `Eu desenvolvi uma app (em Android e IOS)` desenvolveu onde? Nunca usei flash na vida, mas um amigo meu ja fez varios apps usando o adobeair (e tambem o ADT como IDE), e compila direto no celular

Comment: isso se voce tiver o codigo fonte, se tiver somente os swfs, ai nao tenho ideia

Comment: Correcção: Desenvolvi PARA Android, com Adobe Air e Actionscript 3.0.
Essa solução não é possível pois a cada semana saem swf's novos, e o cliente quer que o reprodutor (aplicação) esteja separado dos recursos.
Faço-me entender?

Comment: Agora sim ficou claro, nesse caso nao tem jeito nao, só fazendo o app baixar os SWFs quando tiver atualizacao, ou Atualizar o app toda semana, mas a apple demora pra atualizar entao vai sempre ficar 1 semana atrasado, ai nao da.

Comment: Localmente não há meio?
Já equacionei a hipótese de converter os .swf em .epub e assim manter a interactividade, mas ao que parece, um .epub carregado numa aplicação não têm um desempenho fiável.

Comment: Pelo que entendi voce quer adicionar novos conteudo apos o app instalado certo? Mas sem precisar atualizar o app com o conteudo novo é isso mesmo?

Comment: Exactamente. Eu queria uma app que podias adicionar os novos conteúdos externamente, e a main app continuava a mesma.

Comment: Entao, e onde o usuario vai conseguir esse novo conteudo, pensa assim, ele vai ter que, por exemplo, como voce disse, baixar o swf e carregar no celular via itunes? Voce nao concorda que para o usuario seria muito mais facil fazer isso pelo app?

Comment: Amigo, tu tens razão, mas neste caso não posso por indicações superiores, nem fazer download do conteúdo (pela app) nem compilar os swf com a app. Tenho de os carregar via ficheiro externo.
Não há mesmo solução possível?

Comment: Eu nao conheco nenhum outra alternativa, se voce fez o app para ios sabe muito bem como ele é "travado/fechado" para essas coisas. Ou é do jeito que a apple quer, ou já era. E se a aaple nao aceita swf pelo itunes fica dificil.

Comment: Talvez se voce fizer jailbreak no iphone pode ser que consiga, mas acredito que obrigar o usuario a fazer isso para usar o app é inviavel

Comment: Tens toda a razão, é totalmente inviável e despropositado.
Embora não tenhamos chegado a uma solução, obrigado pela ajuda :)